# Condition to bill a different subscription depending on currency with Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm trying to post different subscriptions based on the currency the user selects on the drop down list. The menu is:

```
 <form action="charge.php" method="post">
    <h3>Sign up to get a new quote every day! Just &euro;400 a month! <small>(Subscription)</small></h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="subscription_purchase" value="subscription_purchase" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

    <select name="currency" value="currency" method="post">
        <option value="euro">Euro</option>
        <option value="dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="rand">RND</option>
        <option value="pounds">GBP</option>
    </select>
    <script 
      src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
      data-amount=40000
      data-description="Wilde monthly subscription"
      data-label="Checkout">
    </script>
</form>
```

and the conditions that I am trying to test are the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && isset($_POST['currency' == 'euro']))
            {
                $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
                    'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'], 
                    'plan' => 'monthly',
                    'description' => 'Subscription'
                ));
            }

            else if(isset($_POST['subscription_purchase']) && isset($_POST['currency' == 'dollar']))
            {
                $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
                    'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'], 
                    'plan' => 'monthly_USD',
                    'description' => 'Subscription'
                ));
            }
```

I think the error falls at the currency in the if statement but I dont know how to correct the logic. So the problem is that the if conditions fail and execute the else statement following this code, I'm missing something but don't have the experience to see it. Thanks in advance, Conor.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but have you created the relevant plans in the Stripe dashboard?

Comment: I have yeah, 'monthly' is in euro and 'monthly_USD' is in dollars

Comment: what happens if you remove the `isset` check for the currency and just use `&& $_POST['currency'] == 'euro'`?

Comment: I've tried echoing it out, I am getting the selections that I want returned to me but now it says:

"Received unknown parameter: plan"

it works fine without the &&

Comment: also, there is no change when I remove isset

Comment: Have you tried just creating a customer without any `if` comparisons just to make sure your code to do that is all correct?

Comment: Yes it all works fine until I add the && isset($_POST['currency' == 'euro'] or without the isset. Then I get the "Received unknown parameter: plan". Once this code is added in then it breaks.